# reading line by line in C and identifying elements

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file which its line is of that form.

```
39.546147  19.849505  Name  Last
```

and I don't know how many lines do I have. What I want is to read text line by line and simple keep in separates variables each of these 4 elements. (2 floats and 2 stings -char[] in that case.)

My code so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE * file1;

file1 = fopen("args.txt","r");
float var0;
float var1;
char S1 [128];
char S2 [128];
int assignments;

if ( file1 != NULL ){
    char line [ 256 ];
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file1 ) != NULL ) //read a line
    {
        //printf("%s\n",line);
        assignments = fscanf( file1, "%f %f %s %s",&var0, &var1, &S1, &S2 );
            if( assignments < 4 ){
                fprintf( stderr, "Oops: only %d fields read\n", assignments );
            }
        printf("%f --- %f ---- %s ---- %s  \n",var0, var1,S1,S2);
    }
    fclose ( file1 );

}
else {
    perror ( "args.txt" ); /* why didn't the file open? */
}
return 0;
}
```

and the result I get is that it read only one element. Can you help me on that?

example of args.txt

```
39.546147  19.849505  george  papad 

39.502277  19.923813  nick  perry 

39.475508  19.934671  john  derrick
```

Comment: Can you add a copy of the args.txt file? Or a link to a pastebin of it?

Comment: Are the empty lines part of the input file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
assignments = fscanf( file1, "%f %f %s %s",&var0, &var1, &S1, &S2 );
```

by

```
assignments = sscanf( line, "%f %f %s %s",&var0, &var1, &S1, &S2 );
```

Update: the program below works here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE * file1;

float var0;
float var1;
char S1 [128];
char S2 [128];
char line [ 256 ];
int assignments;

file1 = fopen("args.txt","r");

if ( file1 == NULL ){
        perror ( "args.txt" ); /* why didn't the file open? */
        return 1;
        }

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file1 ) != NULL ) //read a line
    {
        //printf("%s\n",line);
        assignments = sscanf( line, "%f %f %s %s",&var0, &var1, S1, S2 );
            if( assignments < 4 ){
                fprintf( stderr, "Oops: only %d fields read\n", assignments );
                continue; /* <<----- */
            }
        printf("%f --- %f ---- %s ---- %s  \n",var0, var1,S1,S2);
    }
    fclose ( file1 );

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT (for the input file with the empty lines)

```
39.546146 --- 19.849504 ---- george ---- papad  
Oops: only -1 fields read
39.546146 --- 19.849504 ---- george ---- papad  
39.502277 --- 19.923813 ---- nick ---- perry  
Oops: only -1 fields read
39.502277 --- 19.923813 ---- nick ---- perry  
39.475510 --- 19.934671 ---- john ---- derrick
```

This is expected, there should be a continue (or the equivalent) in the oops-block.

I added the continue to illustrate.

Output for the program WITH the continue:

```
39.546146 --- 19.849504 ---- george ---- papad  
Oops: only -1 fields read
39.502277 --- 19.923813 ---- nick ---- perry  
Oops: only -1 fields read
39.475510 --- 19.934671 ---- john ---- derrick
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a line of text with fgets and then discarding it (since you read again with fscanf).

Instead of calling fgets as your while loop guard, consider using the function feof. The loop guard would therefore become

```
while(!feof(file1))
```

Comment: wrong. The original is correct. (except for the second fscanf())